# What is "private function" mean?

Tags: word-usage

One day, I saw a small sign in front of a wine bar:
"Private function "Mr..." "Company name" 
What is "private function" stand for in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that Mr Blank has hired the whole bar for a social event for his company, so it is temporarily closed to the public (or maybe a section of it is).

Answer (score -1):

In the future, please try to find such answers in a dictionary before asking here.

from [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/private):

> **private** ADJECTIVE
>   1.1 (of a conversation, activity, or gathering) involving only a particular person or group, and often dealing with matters that are not to be disclosed to others.
>
> **function** NOUN
>   4 A large or formal social event or ceremony.

Comment: Knowing the separate dictionary definitions of these two words may not be enough for understanding the real purpose of the sign, which is to keep away everybody who hasn't been invited to the specified function.